# Error on flattening with some pdf with pdf-lib (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to flatten form but got error:

```
const URL = await blobToURL(files[0]); 
const pdfDoc = await PDFDOcument.load(URL, {ignoreEncryption:true}); 
const form = pdfDoc.getForm(); 
form.flatten()); //...
```

Expected instance of PDFDict2, but got instance of undefined
...
at PDFForm2.flatten (PDFForm.ts:539:12)

The PDF:
every PDF in this website:
https://catalogue.servicecanada.gc.ca/content/EForms/en/Detail.html?Form=EMP5611
eg: https://catalogue.servicecanada.gc.ca/content/EForms/en/CallForm.html?Lang=en&PDF=ESDC-EMP5611.pdf

In any normal pdf, it's working

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the source PDF we see the pages entry in the catalogue
`/Pages 543 0 R/StructTreeRoot 106 0 R/Type/Catalog>>`
However the file is heavily encoded so we need to decompress to see that entry

This will then show a different set of data but easier to follow
`/Pages 6 0 R/StructTreeRoot 7 0 R/Type /Catalog`
we may note in passing `<pdfx:NbPage>3</pdfx:NbPage>` indicating 3 pages of XML
and object 6 confirms 3 PDF pages
`6 0 obj <</Count 3/Kids[24 0 R 25 0 R 26 0 R]/Type/Pages>> endobj`

So it will appear to be a 3 page PDF with AcroForm data fields..

However the file with 3 XML pages is a clear indication this is not a simple PDF form but one in 2 guises, A static XFA in a PDF outer, also on inspection is JavaScript enhanced. Now as "static" it may be possible in some cases to flatten but should be treated the same way as a dynamic one.

Such XFA Forms inside a single PDF page need specialist flattening (usually a commercial library) the best description from Adobes Partner for Developers explain it this way.

> XFA PDFs aren’t true PDFs, but PDFs with interactive and dynamic XFA forms embedded in them. Most XFA documents are completely unintelligible to most PDF software and simply can’t be processed at all creating widespread challenges in forms processing workflows....these forms were deprecated in PDF 2.0 with little to no support for the millions of XFA documents still in circulation. How can you work with these types of forms?

> PDF Forms Flattener 3.0.0 was recently released with some great new features, including new import, export, and conversion options. Users can now import and export data from XFA and AcroForm documents to several new formats to best meet their needs. New conversion options have been added as well, including the ability to convert XFA documents to AcroForms documents using the ‘-c’ parameter and more.

> Download a free trial and start using today.
> https://www.datalogics.com/how-to-flatten-xfa-pdf

With a fixed layout "Static" XFA it may be easiest to "Virtually Flatten" by simply reprint as visible data. But you do need to test the results are as expected. Interactive fields may need to be run using a scripted reader before printing.

\for Python you could try Open Source https://github.com/AF-VCD/pdf-xfa-tools

For others there are alternative commercial offerings per Apryse itext

> Adobe LiveCycle ES can flatten XFA forms and iText can flatten filled out XFA forms if you use the closed source XFA Worker addon.

But for node.js, you may need to search around for a good alternative to printing.

Note many libraries may have dependency on pdf-lib and thus we see
https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/blob/93dd36e85aa659a3bca09867d2d8fac172501fbe/src/api/form/PDFTextField.ts#L659 Which shows as comments

```
   * Note that `pdf-lib` does not support reading or writing rich text fields.
   * Nor do most PDF readers and writers. Rich text fields are based on XFA
   * (XML Forms Architecture). Relatively few PDFs use rich text fields or XFA.
   * Unlike PDF itself, XFA is not an ISO standard. XFA has been deprecated in
   * PDF 2.0:
   * * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFA
   * * http://blog.pdfshareforms.com/pdf-2-0-release-bid-farewell-xfa-forms/
```

Pertinently
https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/blob/b8a44bd24b74f4f32456e9809dc4d2d9dc9bf176/src/api/form/PDFForm.ts#L96 shows a test !

````
/**
   * Returns `true` if this [[PDFForm]] has XFA data. Most PDFs with form
   * fields do not use XFA as it is not widely supported by PDF readers.
   *
   * > `pdf-lib` does not support creation, modification, or reading of XFA
   * > fields.
   *
   * For example:
   * ```js
   * const form = pdfDoc.getForm()
   * if (form.hasXFA()) console.log('PDF has XFA data')
   * ```
   * @returns Whether or not this form has XFA data.
   */
  hasXFA(): boolean {
    return this.acroForm.dict.has(PDFName.of('XFA'));
  }
````